# Systemd BindsTo - restart after crashed service

Tags: linux, systemd, crash

My system has multiple systemd services, lets call them `a.service` through `z.service`. As long as all of these services are running, my system is considered "running".

This status shall be indicated somewhere, i.e. on a device status LED. For that I thought of using another systemd service, lets call it `system-status.service`, that does the following:

- When all services are `active` indicate running
- When any of the services crashes/is stopped indicate not running

Using this INCOMPLETE snippet `system-status.service` is running fine except for one scenario:

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=a.service
BindsTo=b.service
...

After=a.service
After=b.service 
...

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/indicate-running.sh
ExecStop=/usr/bin/indicate-stopped.sh
```

However, if `a.service` contains the line `Restart=always`, and `a.service` crashes (simulated through `kill -9`), `a.service` is successfully restartet, but `system-status.service` is not!

```
kill -9 <a.pid>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need would be a `Wants=system-status.service` relationship on both `a.service` and `b.service`. Assuming that you do not want to add an override to both of these services, you should add the reverse relation to the install section of `system-status.service`:

```
...

[Install]
WantedBy=a.service
WantedBy=b.service
```

For this section to have an effect, you must run a `systemctl enable system-status.service` again.